# Move/Swipe Images right and left using Mouse Events using Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, swipe

I have a stack of images. When I move my mouse pointer to left it should display the next image on the stack. When I move the mouse to right it should take me to another page.

JSFiddle [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aqp7xdu0/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image1 image"></div>
    <div class="image2 image"></div>
    <div class="image3 image"></div>
    <div class="image4 image"></div>
    <div class="image5 image"></div>
</div>
```

The design is much like [Tinder Application on Phones].
Here are a few links where it is achieved by jquery:

[Tinder Animation](https://codepen.io/arjentienkamp/pen/MYpYMO)

[Swipe Cards](https://codepen.io/mochiron/pen/Jatrb)

How can I do this with pure JavaScript?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aqp7xdu0/

Comment: Reworded and added relevant JSFiddle demo from comment to Q.

Comment: Would you like to drag the card left/right or just hover over left part of the image?

Comment: @MartinGottweis Yes, I would like to drag it to left/right

Answer (score -1):

You want to capture the mouse coordinates at some start position, then capture the `onmousemove` event to get new coordinates. Look at the difference vector (maybe convert it to polar coordinates first) to decide whether it's moved far enough to trigger another action.